# AngularJS Trying to Fetch Images Json file and render a template broke something

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Another Update

I got it turns out the routeparams.Id is not working because I am using ui-router and not routeprovider to define my routes. You can use $stateParams instead.

**Updated**

I fixed my data.json file but my detail.html partial is not rendered correctly.

I changed it to

```
Hi

<ul class="backpageimages">
    <li ng-repeat="img in extrainfo.images">
        <img ng-src="{{img}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

the hi is getting rendered which means its routing correctly but the console says

```
GET http://localhost:8000/data/undefined.json 404 (File not found)
```

It can not find my 1.json file.

now my controller looks like this

```
backpageApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('data/' + $routeParams.listingId + '.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.listingId = $routeParams.listingId; /* added this explicity */
      $scope.extrainfo = data; 
  });
});
```

If it helps the url is this

```
http://localhost:8000/#/listings/1
```

---

Hi guys I am new to angular js and its trying to build a small Backpage in angular js. I am using the sample from the angularjs official tutorial at step 7 and step 8

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08

I am trying to fetch a json file with images which point to pictures in my folders locally. These will be displayed in another view.

This is a file called 1.json in my data folder. The file is validated json file.

```
{
    "images": [
        "images/pic1.jpg",
        "images/pic2.jpg",
        "images/pic3.jpg",
        "images/pic4.jpg",
        "images/pic5.jpg",
        "images/pic6.jpg",
        "images/pic7.jpg"
    ],

    "description": "The last room to be rented in a house of 4 bedrooms mostly young professionals students all females."
}
```

Here is a snippet of data.json file also in my data folder

```
{
         "date":12012013,
         "id":1,
         "rent":600,
         "location": "East Boston",
         "title": "room close to transportation Jan 1st (East Boston) ",
        }
```

The 1.json corresponds with my id of 1 in my data.json. 
In my module I made sure I added 'ngRoute' as a dependency

```
var backpageApp = angular.module('backpageApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
```

I downloaded the angular-route.js and added it to my index.html

```
<script src="js/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
```

I have this controller that fetches the images according to the id

```
backpageApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('data/' + $routeParams.listingId + '.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.extrainfo = data; 
  });
});
```

I am using ui router so my state looks like this

```
.state('listingdetail', {
      url: "/listings/:listingId",
      templateUrl: "partials/detail.html",
      controller: 'SecondCtrl'
    })
```

Here is my detail.html

```
{{extrainfo.description}}



<ul class="pictures">
    <li ng-repeat="img in extrainfo.images">
        <img ng-src="{{img}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what its returning in my chrome dev tool

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
 app.js:25
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Line 25 is a console log for my first controller. I am a bit lost. I am not sure which part of the step did I break the rendering. Also I have this in my index.html

```
<a href="#/listings/{{listing.id}}">
        Title:{{listing.title}}</a>
```

I have a data.json file returned using $resource in my firstctrl and stored in a $scope.listings. My ultimate goal is when someone click that title, it will direct the user to my detail partial with images displayed.

maybe I am suppose to put this explicitly in my secondctrl

```
$scope.listingId = $routeParams.listingId;
```

Comment: your $routeParams.listingId is coming back as undefined. console.log $routeParams and see what is there.

Answer (score 3):

Your json file is invalid.  Remove the last comma and make sure to validate them using a service like http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to avoid simple errors.

```
{
         "date":12012013,
         "id":1,
         "rent":600,
         "location": "East Boston",
         "title": "room close to transportation Jan 1st (East Boston) ",  // <---- remove comma 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it turns out the routeparams.Id is not working because I am using ui-router and not routeprovider to define my routes. You can use $stateParams instead.

also I needed to remove an extra comma from my data.json